# Content showing well formated in frontend but in editing mode it's showing html codes

Tags: html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinnymce editor in textarea sections of my project.
when i am inserting the content inserting in database as html code like

```html
<p>Hello, its a test post</p><br/>
```

but its showing in frontend pretty nice.

the probleme is when i am going to edit page to update the post content are showing as html raw code same to same in data base like

```html
<p>Hello, its a test post</p><br/>
```

thats why i can't see the images in contents.

please help me to fix the probleme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some aspect of your application is escaping the HTML when you go to reload it into TinyMCE.  When you want to load the content back into the editor you need to load HTML that has not been escaped.

Comment: oh yes..   i returned  value in set_value() function.. that's why its escaping HTML..

Comment: If that fixed the issue can you select this answer as correct so people know the issue is resolved?